# How to refresh list as another record is added into DB

Tags: angular

my html page is using 2 angular components. For 1 component I am displaying a list of players using an api call. I want this list to refresh as soon as another player record is added into DB. I am using mongoDB for back-end. How to achieve this? I am very new to angular and web development. please help.

Comment: Angular has no direct knowledge of what is happening in the database. You could either poll at a regular interval to the backend, or better use a SSE to send data streams from the backend to Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subject of design that comes up often. There are several ways to achieve the desired result.

1. Effectively as said above, reload the list completely to update it.
2. When adding a resource to your database, you return the newly created resource. Therefore you will be able to add to the list. You just need to "subscribe" to your create method and pass the created resource to the component that manages the list.
3. A little more complicated to set up, a web socket system to carry out operations in real time.
4. Use Firebase with the real-time database system to avoid coding everything by hand.

Hope to have helped you a little, good evening

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

```
const source = timer(1,10000);

const subscribe = source.subscribe(
  x => {this.playerService.getPlayerByGame(p1).subscribe( 
          (data) => {this.playerslist = data;

  //console.log("playerslist.length:"+this.playerslist.length);
  return this.playerslist;
  });
});
```